# while training with the opennlp training api command getting java heap space error:

Tags: java, out-of-memory, opennlp

I am using opennlp training api as shown below:

> Blockquote opennlp DoccatTrainer -model en-doccat.bin -lang en -data Task_notes_1new.train -encoding ISO-8859-1
>   Blockquote
>   this api creates a model named en-doccat.bin from the training dataset 
>   Task_notes_1new.train.

while training with the above command getting following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at opennlp.maxent.GISTrainer.trainModel(GISTrainer.java:301)
    at opennlp.maxent.GIS.trainModel(GIS.java:256)
    at opennlp.model.TrainUtil.train(TrainUtil.java:184)
    at opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentCategorizerME.train(DocumentCategorizerME.java:162)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.doccat.DoccatTrainerTool.run(DoccatTrainerTool.java:61)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CLI.main(CLI.java:222)
```

I even tried increasing the heap size upto 4GB, still the error remains the same.

Comment: yeah it got solved, My training data set had 1700 separate classes that is why opennlp was not able to train it self due to the large storage it would require to store all those classes.