# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space:failed reallocation of scalar replaced objects - Error when train the custom model using opennlp api

Tags: java, out-of-memory, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am getting below error when I train a custom NER model using openNlp api with more than 2 million sentences.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space:failed reallocation of scalar replaced objects.
```

I tried below solution but its not working for me.

- Increasing the heap size, via "-Xmx1024m" (or more),

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337671/while-training-with-the-opennlp-training-api-command-getting-java-heap-space-err